# How to get performance of Eigen Matrix operator+ in C++

Tags: c++, performance, operator-overloading, eigen, rvalue-reference

I'm converting from Eigen matrix to my own code.
While I convert it, I wondered about performance of Eigen Matrix operator+

I've tested with below code(Using Eigen Matrix)

```
Eigen::MatrixXd Mat(6, 6); Mat <<  698.28622975817, 7655.16788149002, 7093.64830858073, 1189.97681558377, 712.67059305653, 472.15529963803,
    3170.99480060861, 791.99901137063, 756.86681982361, 4983.64051982143, 2550.95115459269, 1386.24442828679,
    9502.22048838355, 1868.72604554379, 270.25076998578, 9597.43958516081, 5059.57051665142, 1492.94005559057,
    344.460805029088, 4897.64395788231, 697.02676853675, 3403.85726666133, 6990.76722656686, 2575.08254123736,
    4387.44359656398, 4455.86200710900, 6550.98003973841, 5852.67750979777, 8909.03252535799, 8407.17255983663,
    3815.58457093008, 6463.13010111265, 1626.11735194631, 2238.11939491137, 9592.91425205444, 2542.82178971531 ;

Eigen::MatrixXd Result;

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point StartTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Result = Mat + Mat;
}
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point EndTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::nanoseconds CalTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(EndTime - StartTime);
std::cout << "Calculate Time : " << CalTime.count() << std::endl;
```

It took time about 1800ns

And I have wrote my own operator+ code and have tested with below code(my code[try - 1, try - 2])

```
//Matrix.h

// operator=
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(Matrix&& matrix) noexcept
{
    m_Data = matrix.m_Data;
    m_Num = matrix.m_Num;
    m_Row = matrix.m_Row;
    m_Column = matrix.m_Column;

    matrix.m_Row = matrix.m_Column = m_Num = 0;
    matrix.m_Data = nullptr;

    return *this;
}


///try 1 - start
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& matrix)
{
    return Matrix(*this) += matrix;
}


Matrix& Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix& matrix) noexcept
{
    assert(m_Row == matrix.m_Row);
    assert(m_Column == matrix.m_Column);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_Num; ++i)
    {
        m_Data[i] += matrix.m_Data[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
///try 1 - end

///try 2 - start
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& matrix)
{
    Matrix mat(matrix.m_Row, matrix.m_Column); //set size by initializer

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.m_Num; i++)
    {
        mat.m_Data[i] = this->m_Data[i] + matrix.m_Data[i];
    }

    return std::move(mat);
}
///try 2 - end


//main.cpp
double A[36] = { 698.28622975817, 7655.16788149002, 7093.64830858073, 1189.97681558377, 712.67059305653, 472.15529963803,
    3170.99480060861, 791.99901137063, 756.86681982361, 4983.64051982143, 2550.95115459269, 1386.24442828679,
    9502.22048838355, 1868.72604554379, 270.25076998578, 9597.43958516081, 5059.57051665142, 1492.94005559057,
    344.460805029088, 4897.64395788231, 697.02676853675, 3403.85726666133, 6990.76722656686, 2575.08254123736,
    4387.44359656398, 4455.86200710900, 6550.98003973841, 5852.67750979777, 8909.03252535799, 8407.17255983663,
    3815.58457093008, 6463.13010111265, 1626.11735194631, 2238.11939491137, 9592.91425205444, 2542.82178971531 };

Matrix Mat = { A, 6, 6 };

Matrix Result(0.0, 6, 6);
//Matrix Result;
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point StartTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Result = Mat + Mat;
}
```

try - 1 result was 24000 ns

try - 2 result was 18000 ns

Both took longer time than Eigen Matrix operator+(about 10 times)

Is there any trick for operator+ of Eigen Matrix?
How can I reduce operating time? Could anyone share the C++ performance skill?
Thank you for read

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell, since you did not provide a complete [mre], but I assume your `operator+` does involve some allocation and copying, whereas Eigen just does in-place assignment (once `Result` is allocated). This might be an interesting read: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicInsideEigenExample.html

Comment: Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& matrix) const. Or even better a free function that return a const object http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/004.htm. I guess that the compiler could optimize something away in your loop.

Comment: How the program is compiled? Did you enabled optimization?

Comment: @chtz Thanks for your answer. It is powerful answer. But my understanding is so poor T.T. I guess it would be helpful to me. I'm reading it about half day haha.